# badge giver help (roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I'm working on a Roblox game, I want to make a secret room and award players a badge for finding it, but the problem is that the badge giver is not working, my badge giver is also locked so that I don't accidentally put it in a map. It's also behind a code door and surrounded by locked parts. Here is my code.

```
local badgeService = game:GetService("BadgeService")
local id = 2133435079

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        
        local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
        badgeService:AwardBadge(plr.UserId,id)
    end
end)
```

I tried unlocking the badge giver but that didn't work.

I also tried regular test but that also didn't work

Comment: Are there any errors or messages in the Output widget?

Comment: Yeah, "Workspace.Part.Script:9: attempt to index nil with 'UserId'", I think the error involves this line: badgeService:AwardBadge(plr.UserId,id)

Comment: Also, I'm doing it in test mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error, it sounds like you're not protecting against the case that `plr` is nil. This can happen if `hit.Parent` isn't a player's character model.

```lua
local badgeService = game:GetService("BadgeService")
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local id = 2133435079

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local plr = players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if plr then
        badgeService:AwardBadge(plr.UserId, id)
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also try switching to a local script and use this
it might not work cuz im not that good at luau

```
local badgeservice = game:GetService("BadgeService")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local id = 123456789

    script.Parent.Baseplate.Touched:Connect(function()
        if player then
            badgeservice:AwardBadge(player.UserId, id)
        elseif not player then
            warn("This is not a player")
        end
        
    end)
```